# Miscellany vs. Other things

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

In technical texts, there is often a section that includes things that are not listed in other sections. What is the common way to name it, "Miscellany", "Other things", or something different?

Comment: "Miscellaneous" or even the abbreviation "misc." is the only way I've ever seen this kind of section titled.

Comment: The last document I needed this for I called it Miscellanea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "miscellaneous".

From the [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miscellaneous):

> consisting of a mixture of various things that are not usually connected with each other